# Three.js loading exported blender model

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, blender

I did a simple 3d model in blender and exported it to .obj file. Now I am loading it using three.js and I want objects that have string 'clickable' in its name to move on Y axis on click.

You can look at it here: http://three.parkz.cz/shop.html

The problem is that the informations parsed from names of objects (which I set in blender) are not corresponding to the right objects.

Loading and parsing:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  object = event.content;
  object.name = 'CustomObjects';
  for(var i = 0; i < object.children.length; i++) {      

    //console.log(object.children[i]);
    var properties = object.children[i].name.split('_');
    if(properties[1] == 'clickable') {
      object.children[i].clickable = true; 
    } else object.children[i].clickable = false;

  }
  object.rotation.x = 0.5;
  object.rotation.y = 0.5;                                  
  scene.add(object);
});
loader.load('shop.obj', 'shop.mtl');
```

For example that two cubes in the center (called '005_kiosek' and '010_kiosek2') are not supposed to be clickable but they are! You can open console and after click on it you can see that they are named wrongly '004_clickable' and '009_clickable'!

Here is my blender file: http://three.parkz.cz/shop.blend

Is it problem on javascript side or blender exports it wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Martin

P.S: Does anybody know why aren't that simple meshes (green and blue) rendered well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The green and blue mesh are not rendered correctly because, under the current implementation, the obj loader only accepts triangles as faces. As those meshes use polygons, they are not rendered correctly.

As for the names I would try to verify that what I put in the blender file, comes out correct. So when you load the model, just print the name and its clickable attribute, to see if all is correct instead for taking it for granted.

Comment: Hi Gaitat, thank you for the response! I'll try to verify if blender exports everything well. Could you please advise how to fix the problem with rendering? Should I model the object differently in blender?

Comment: Yes, when you export from blender, there should be an option to triangulate the faces of the model.

Comment: Rendering problem is solved, gonna play with clickable now. Thank you! You really helped me.

Comment: Hi Gaitat, the problem is that first two loaded meshes have the same parent. You can see it in console in my updated example: http://three.parkz.cz/shop.html Do you think it's problem in blender export or the way how three.js loads the scene?http://three.parkz.cz/shop.blend Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you printing the parent. I just looked in the OBJMTLLoader and the parent group does not get a name. So you must be printing something random. Try doing `object.name = something` right after `objects = event.content;`. All the objects then should have the same parent as the obj file suggests.

Comment: Ok so I've added    objects.name = 'CustomObjects'; and when I look at the children of this object: first doesn't have any children (mesh) and the last one has 2 children (meshes). Why does three.js load it this way if I made it separately in blender?

Comment: OK, I just verified that there is nothing wrong with the three.js obj loader. To see for yourself, (I use Chrome debugger) put a stop at the line `object.traverse`. At that point the model has been loaded, the parent has a name and the hierarchy has been printed to the console. Expand the arrows on the left to see that all objects have as parent the `CustomObjects` group, and that each object has a unique id and name.

Comment: Yes all objects have as parent `CustomObjects`, but these objects under `CustomObjects` should have children with mesh. Am I right? And there's the problem. `children[0]` doesn't have any, `[1]` and `[2]` should be OK and `[3]` has two meshes. Also when you click on the object you should get its respective name in the console, but it's somehow shifted. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you are right. I think you should create an issue at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues but make more clear so people would have to go into the debugger to verify the problem. Print your hierarhy tree with names and number of children.

Comment: Ok, thank you Gaitat for you effort in solving the problem! Have a nice day!

Comment: One suggestion so you can continue your work would be to save separate obj files (ie. one model for the sphere, one for the cone, etc.)